# pandas install in python in win10 x64 bit

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I installed numpy, pandas downloaded online from this site https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. No problem came in installing when i tried to import pandas this error is coming

[image]

what should i do?

Comment: In my opinion the easiest is install [anaconda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/windows.html) and then install pandas by `conda install pandas` in cmd.

Comment: In the future copy/paste the error message and quote it in the question instead of using a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

> This post may be deleted again for insufficient answer, but as someone who's been in a position not knowing what terms to search for when encountering these issues and wasted hours with no one telling me what to do..
>
> > I see the issue is caused by importing pandas in your case, but try searching with the error message printed. That usually leads to more clues.
> >     Last line reads 'AttributeError: module numpy has no attribute float128'
> >     There are threads on this matter on google, work from there on.